# Make ShowHint work on custom control with several different Rects, each with their own Hint

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder, vcl

Using C++ Builder 2009

I have a custom control that inherits from `TCustomControl`, on which I paint several squares (`TRect`) with content etc.

I now wanted to show Hint as I hover over every square, but I'm not sure how to implement this best.

I attempted to simply use `TCustomControl`'s `ShowHint`, and change `Hint` as I hover over the squares, but the problem is that the control doesn't show hint anymore after it first disappears, unless I leave the control and come back to it.
I hoped I could simply 'reset' it's state while hovering from one square to another but it doesn't work.

Assuming my approach is wrong to start with, kindly let me know what I should do to get the desired effect ?

```
if (State == rsHover && Item->FState != rsHover) // Not in the rsHover state yet, but going to
    {
    if (Item->Hint.Length())
        {
        if (ShowHint)
            {
            // Attempt to reset Hint's internal working, to no avail
            Hint = L"" ;
            ShowHint = false ;
            }

        Hint = Item->Hint ;

        ShowHint = true ;
        }
    else
        {
        ShowHint = false ;
        }
    }
else if (State != rsHover)
    {
    ShowHint = false ;
    }
```

Comment: This may not directly address your question, but for more complicated hint scenarios, I've had good luck with the following: (1) Create invisible TGraphicsControls (i.e., TGraphicsControls that don't draw anything) in the coordinates I want and assign their Hint properties. (2) Use the JVCL's TJvBalloonHint.

Comment: why is the delphi tag there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to implement this feature is to make your component handle the `CM_HINTSHOW` message.  The message's `LParam` value will be a pointer to a [`THintInfo`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Forms.THintInfo) record, whose fields you can freely modify as needed (in particular, `HintStr` and `CursorRect`).

To access the record, you can either

- type-cast the `LParam` directly to `THintInfo*`.
- type-cast the entire `TMessage` to [`TCMHintShow`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Controls.TCMHintShow), and then access its `HintInfo` field.

By defining your own `CursorRect` rectangles, you can "[divide your control] into several hint regions", each with a different `HintStr` value.  The `CursorPos` field indicates the mouse's current position within the control. When the mouse moves outside of the current `CursorRect`, the control will receive a new `CM_HINTSHOW` message, and you can update the `CursorRect` and `HintStr` fields as needed.

Comment: Thanks, it was an easy and straightforward implementation.

Comment: I'm actually a bit confused how this relates to `CustomHint`.  Are both different Hints that can work alongside or does one take over from the other, if assigned ?

Comment: `CustomHint` uses a completely different mechanism for displaying hints. It is not tied into the `TApplication`-based hint system at all. If `CustomHint` is assigned, it takes over hint management, and your component cannot influence the behavior of that system at all, other than to provide the string that is displayed (via its normal `Hint` property).